# Android dagger hilt module communication

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

If in my project i have app module and 2 other modules : Module1 and Module2. App depends on Module1 and Module2. Module 1 does not depend on Module 2 (and vice versa)

What setup i need to be able cu access Module2 form Module1? if possible

Thanks

Comment: You just said Module 1 does not depend on Module 2.  So why would it access it?  If it's accessing it, that's a dependency

Comment: Yep. Maybe something bridge  through app module in reverse from module 1 to module 2